# How to share a MacBook Pro's Internet with a Nokia mobile

Tags: macbook-pro, nokia-n-series, reverse-tethering

I have an Internet connection on a MacBook Pro and a Nokia mobile. Is it possible to share the MacBook Pro's Internet with the Nokia phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What phone do you have? If you don't have WiFi but do have Symbian on your Nokia, it should be possible to do this with bluetooth and an extra app:

http://dailymobile.se/2009/03/17/guide-how-to-share-your-pc-internet-connection-with-your-mobile-phone/

The explanation is for a Windows PC, but hopefully it'll work on a Mac too, since it's Java.

If you don't have Symbian (ie a Nokia s40) phone, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Im using nokia n79

Comment: well that has symbian, so this solution should work. but it seems to also have WLAN, so the other answer could be a possibility too.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://www.macyourself.com/2009/02/23/turn-your-mac-into-a-wifi-hotspot-using-os-xs-internet-sharing/) for a step by step method on how to convert you mac into  a wifi hotspot .
This will work only if you have WiFi on your phone

Comment: Im asking about mac to nokia. not for nokia to mac.

Comment: have edited the answer